# EF-Core: Equals() not worked to check null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

when i used Equals() , not worked and returned null but after replace Equals() with Equality(==), It worked properly

```
var a = await _context.OrganizationalRoleAssignments
                            .Where(
                                 x => x.OrganizationalRoleId.Equals(organizationalRoleId)
                                  && x.UnassignUtcDate.Equals(null)
                                  && x.UnassignCause.Equals(null)
                             ).ToListAsync();



await _context.OrganizationalRoleAssignments
                            .Where(
                                 x => x.OrganizationalRoleId.Equals(organizationalRoleId)
                                  && x.UnassignUtcDate == null
                                  && x.UnassignCause == null
                             ).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `Equals` != `==` :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123888/linq-what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-a-join

Comment: It depends on what the type of UnassignUtcDate and UnassignCause is and which of `Equals` and `operator==` it overrides.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if an object is null in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417902/checking-if-an-object-is-null-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Entity Framework, both 'classic' and Core, operators such as `==` are recognized in the Expression parse tree. A C# comparison like **`x.something == null`** will get translated to **`x.something IS NULL`** in the generated SQL.

The same translation is most likely not being done for `x.something.Equals(null)`.

---

Quoting from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/standard-query-operator-translation#null-semantics):

> A *comparison with the literal null* is translated to the appropriate SQL version (**is null** or **is not null**).

The document above was written for .NET Framework + LINQ to SQL of that time, but it largely still applies to EF Core. So far I did not find a more up-to-date reference of the same nature.

Comment: Not 100% certain but we could assume, despite the lack of proper tags/information in que question, that the question is Linq to SQL. Very likely this answer adresses the problem.

Comment: @Cleptus I doubt that LINQ to SQL has `ToListAsync` support. I think we can safely assume the OP is using EF or EF Core.