# Reason of equals keyword in LINQ's join statement

Tags: linq

Here is a LINQ query:

```
from a in db.Table1
join b in db.Table2 on a.Id1 equals b.Id2
```

I am wondering the reason of `equals` keyword.

Why did the LINQ creators have to create this keyword? Couldn't they work with `==`?

Is there a particular reason ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq: What is the difference between == and equals in a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123888/linq-what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-a-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#the-equals-operator):

> A `join` clause performs an equijoin. In other words, you can only base matches on the equality of two keys. Other types of comparisons such as "greater than" or "not equals" are not supported. To make clear that all joins are equijoins, the `join` clause uses the `equals` keyword instead of the `==` operator.

That's the main reason. There are also some other difference between `equals` and `==` to make the operator better suitable for LINQ. One important difference is that the operator isn't symmetric. You have to write

```cs
join b in db.Table2 on a.Id1 equals b.Id2
```

Using

```cs
join b in db.Table2 on b.Id1 equals a.Id2
```

throws a compiler error.

Not mentioned (but implicated by the join being an equijoin): another difference is that the operator can't be chained. These join expressions are invalid:

```cs
join b in db.Table2 on a.Id equals b.Id || a.Id equals b.Id2

join b in db.Table2 on a.Id equals b.Id && a.Id2 equals b.Id2
```

The latter join can be coded by using a [composite key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys).

I think it was a great decision to use a special contextual keyword. It makes developers pay attention and doesn't raise expectations that an `==` operator might have done.